# Can import TensorFlow and Keras in Jupyter, even though I have them installed?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I have setup Tensorflow and Keras on Mac OS. I also have Jupyter that came as part of my Anaconda installation.

When I try to import Tensoflow or Keras in a Jupyter notebook, I get "a no module named <...>" error.

Am I missing a step ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your environments. You probably installed everything inside a tensorflow environment, but ran the notebook on the root one.

[The window you want to check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOBOr.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Windows/Mac user who is working on Jupyter notebook, `pip install keras` doesn't help you. Instead, try the steps below:

1. In command prompt navigate to the “site packages” directory of your anaconda installed.
2. Now use `conda install tensorflow` and after `conda install keras`
3. Restart your Jupyter notebook and run the packages.